# Limit Unity's Scope to Virtual Workspace?

Tags: unity

When I click a unity icon it shows smaller versions of all the windows for that program. So for example, if I have 3 terminals open, and click the unity terminal icon I see all 3 windows to select for focus.

Is it possible to limit it to only show windows for the program that exist in the current virtual workspace?

Comment: How have to provide information about which version you're using. This has been changed.

Comment: I did not find anything either but I think it should be a standard features!
Or at least have a key to change from unique virtual desktop to multi virtual desktop!

Answer (score 0):

It's not through unity, but alt-tab switching prefers the last one opened on the current workspace, at least for me.  It also doesn't remove non-current workspace from the hover list or give you a picture of the window though.  Depending on your situation it could work.